# Docker doesn't show information on STDERR

Tags: docker, docker-compose, stderr, apache2.4

I am trying to send the apache error logs to STDERR inside a docker container.
Here's my site-config.conf file regarding the logs:

```
<VirtualHost *:8008>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, here's the relevant part of the Dockerfile:

```
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/test_access.log \
&& ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/test_error.log
```

For the STDOUT it works just fine, but the error log doesn't appear at all in the docker logs.

I even tested this version of the Dockerfile:

```
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/test_access.log \
&& ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/test_error.log
```

And this way the errors appeared. I also verified that I have the `/dev/stderr` file and it points to `/proc/self/fd/2`.

Do you have any clue why the docker logs doesn't contain the STDERR logs?

Comment: Maybe the vhost your'e editing is not used at runtime?

Comment: It is used, because I tried it to access on that specific port and the link is made to the stdout then it works.